# Get heart rate data over bluetooth with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bluetooth, sensors

I am trying to read heart rate data from a POLAR H7 bluetooth device with ASUS BT400 dongle.

Device is paired allready with my computer.

I can see it from MATLAB

```
b=instrhwinfo('Bluetooth')
b = RemoteNames: {2x1 cell}
    RemoteIDs: {2x1 cell}
    BluecoveVersion: 'BlueCove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
    JarFileVersion: 'Version 3.3'

b.RemoteNames
ans = 'Polar H7 1001A1'
      ''
```

But I can't see how many channels it has

```
instrhwinfo('Bluetooth','Polar H7 1001A1')
ans = 

           RemoteName: []
             RemoteID: []
ObjectConstructorName: []
             Channels: []
```

Neither open any channel

```
bt = Bluetooth('Polar H7 1001A1',1)

Bluetooth Object : Bluetooth-Polar H7 1001A1:1

Communication Settings 
  RemoteName:         Polar H7 1001A1
  RemoteID:           btspp://0022D01001A1
  Channel:            1
  Terminator:         'LF'

Communication State 
  Status:             closed
  RecordStatus:       off

Read/Write State  
  TransferStatus:     idle
  BytesAvailable:     0
  ValuesReceived:     0
  ValuesSent:         0

fopen(bt)

Error using icinterface/fopen (line 83)
Unsuccessful open: Cannot connect to the device. Possible reasons are another
application is connected
or the device is not available.
```

There is an open post on matlabcentral
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119338-how-can-i-read-heart-rate-data-from-a-polar-h7-bluetooth-device

But I could not find anything relevant.

Can anyone help ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Saddly, the answer is MATLAB supports only BLUETOOTH SPP PROFILE ...

Answer (score 0):

If you check the port of the Bluetooth device in Device Manager, you can use the following code to open the port and access your Bluetooth device.

```
port=serial('COM40','BaudRate',57600);
fopen(port);
```